# newtxmath with libertine: different 'g' in subscript

Tags: newtxmath

The following example gives me a different 'g' in the simple subscript:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}


\begin{document}
\[g \ \mu_g \ A_{\mu_g}\]

\end{document}
```

Is there a quick way to fix this? (EDIT: Using MiKTex 2.9.7250, compiling the same code with overleaf gives me the "right" 'g' in the subscript.)

**EDIT: This been has been fixed in Version 1.612 (2019-12-01).**

[image]

Comment: Seems like a simple oversight. The gs work fine if the `libertine` option is not active. Contact the maintainer of `newtxmath` and tell them about it ([the project README on CTAN has an email address at the end](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/newtx/README)).

Comment: If you are ok with the “two-storey” shape for the lowercase letter `g` in text, script, and scriptscript math style, I suggest you replace `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` with `\usepackage{libertinust1math}`. (Aside: Michael Shell is the author of both packages.) Note that the latter package does not offer a `varg` option at present; hence, no single-storey `g` in math mode.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, will do.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed by the maintainer: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live-commits/2019-December/011722.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, the `nxlmi` font has the wrong glyph at sizes 10 and 5, while it has the right one at size 7.

Until the issue is fixed at the font level, you can somewhat fix it by telling LaTeX to get the “g” from a different font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{libertineg}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{libertineg}{bold}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathalpha}{libertineg}{`g}

\begin{document}

\[g \ \mu_g \ A_{\mu_g}\ \textit{g}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the “variant g”, it's a bit more complicated: we need to scale down the text style “g” only when in script style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{xfp,graphicx}

\newcommand{\fixg}{{%
  \mathchoice
    {\normalg}% displaystyle
    {\normalg}% textstyle
    {\scaledg}% scriptstyle
    {\normalg}% scriptscriptstyle
}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scaledg}{%
  \scalebox{\fpeval{\sf@size/\f@size}}{$\m@th\normalg$}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`g \lowercase{\endgroup\let~\fixg}
\edef\normalg{\mathchar\the\mathcode`g }
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`g="8000 }

\begin{document}

\[g \ \mu_g \ A_{\mu_g}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I shuld have mentioned that I would like to keep the 'varg' in all instances, i.e., the first 'g' in my picture. Is there a way to adjust the code?

Comment: @Pete I wouldn't, but here it is.

Comment: Thank you! The 'varg' seems to be version intended by the package author (at least with option 'libertine' active). Why would you advise against it?